# How to get HTML5 Cache status by using Selenium JavaScriptExecutor

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium

How to get HTML5 Cache status by using Selenium JavaScriptExecutor?

I tried as below, but didn't get the correct status.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.AppCacheStatus;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.ApplicationCache;

public class Html5AppCache {

    public void testHTML5LocalStorage() throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm");

        JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String cacheStatus = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return  window.applicationCache.status;");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting a wrong status as you are executing the javascript before the page is getting fully loaded

Try to wait for the elements in the page to be loaded before executing the javascript

I also found another problem in the above code the return type is long which cannot be casted to a string you will get a  `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `java.lang.Long` cannot be cast to `java.lang.String`

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[@id='timePara']")));

JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

long cacheStatus = (long) jsExecutor.executeScript("return  window.applicationCache.status;");

System.out.println(cacheStatus);
```

I tried with the above code i was getting the correct status

Hope this helps you...Kindly check it and getback if there are any problems